# Jekyll - How to modularly load scripts?

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to load javascript modularly with [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com)?

Is there a default `_js` directory or a way to set one up, much like [the `_sass`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) but without `@import`?

Comment: what do you mean by  load javascript modularly ? you can you NPM/bower

read it http://nicolashery.com/fast-mobile-friendly-website-with-jekyll/

Comment: meaning using small individual `js` files by default, like you can do with `@import` with and the sass file - so it's all concatenated - I am guessing this isn't possible, probably only with coffee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are expecting is certainly not possible, you can use npm like package managers for getting the files only..
 but may not be able to load them like that.

So what you can do is you can make a custom directive in Angular and manage to add the  tag at run time and restart the Digest cycle so as to get it loaded in the cache

I hope that will solve your issue